# How to find Only hour value in 12hrs format using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want hour value only from the currenttime

Like if it is **4:31:13** so i want only **4** and that also should be in **12hrs** format..

Please help me...

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
case when DATEPART(hh, time) > 12
then DATEPART(hh, time) - 12 
else DATEPART(hh, time) end as hour
from time;
```

[**SAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a2e6/8).

Answer (score 1):

This will also correctly handle 12 AM and 12 PM time:

```
select case datepart(hh, getdate()) 
    when  0 then 12 
    when 12 then 12 
    else datepart(hh, getdate()) % 12 
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) + 11) % 12 + 1
```

At 1 am this will return:

```
1 + 11 = 12; 12 % 12 = 0; 0 + 1 = 1
```

At 1 pm (13:00 in 24 hrs format) you'll get:

```
13 + 11 = 24; 24 % 12 = 0; 0 + 1 = 1
```

Similarly, at 2 am and at 2 pm (14:00):

```
 2 + 11 = 13; 13 % 12 = 1; 1 + 1 = 2
14 + 11 = 25; 25 % 12 = 1; 1 + 1 = 2
```

and so on till 11 am and 11 pm. At 12 am (0:00) & 12 pm (12:00) it will go like this:

```
 0 + 11 = 11; 11 % 12 = 11; 11 + 1 = 12
12 + 11 = 23; 23 % 12 = 11; 11 + 1 = 12
```

Comment: What happens when time is 12 am / 12 pm?

Comment: @Praveen: The expression will return `12` as shown in the last two lines of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, '2008-09-27 09:30:00.000')
```

[Refer this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: In this case it will return 09 but if the time is 16:30:00 i want it to return it 16 as 4

Comment: did you check the refer link ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)),1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database engine are you using, but in PostgreSQL you can do this:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12');
```

Comment: Sorry But i want it in SQl Server 2008